# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$.supersized')

Tags: jquery, wordpress, typeerror

I'm using a WordPress site.
I'm including this script in the header.
When the script loads, I get this error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$.supersized')

`supersized` is a full width background plugin I have on the site.
I have no idea what is causing it or what it even means.

I feel like I deleted a file or a jquery line in my css, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is the path to the script right? check your network console

Comment: Can you post your markup, specifically where you are referencing this plugin script?

Comment: most likely your plugin either isn't loaded correctly, jquery is included twice, or the script references are out of order.

Comment: Oh gosh it seems as though this error was coming up because of another plugin. I deactivated the most recent and the background started to work again. Is there anyone that might be willing to make these 2 plugins work together? lol I've done this a few times, but this background plugin and a scroll bar plugin are a little too complicated for me.

Comment: Does any jQuery functionality work on the page or is it just `supersized` that is broken?

Comment: this *"other plugin"* must be including it's own version of jquery, or overriding/removing `$`

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'll try and attempt to fix that